# Reneder XML on browser using Binary Stream

Tags: java, aem, jcr

I have one xml file in JCR, I want to render this XML over browser via servlet. Below is the code I am using :

```
String path = "/content/geometrixx/en/sitemap.xml/jcr:content";

if(session.nodeExists(path)) {
    Node node = session.getNode(path);
    InputStream inputStream = node.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result = bis.read();
    while (result != -1) {
        byte b = (byte) result;
        buf.write(b);
        result = bis.read();
    }
    out.print(buf.toString());
}
```

But in this way only string gets printed over browser means values of tags not the whole XML. How can I render whole XML to browser.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this code. I created a sample servlet and used the above code in the `doGet()` method and the path of an XML file in the dam and it is working fine. Additional information might help in identifying the issue better.

Comment: My Bad, Issue is was with chrome extension, after installed XML Tree its display XML.